# How to prove that the following sets are dense or not?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $A_1, A_2$ be two dense subsets of $X$. If $E\subseteq X$,  then which of the following are true?

1. $E\cap A_1$ is dense in $E$
2. $E\cap A_1$ is dense in $E$ if $E$ is open
3. $E\cap A_1 \cap A_2$ is dense in $E$ if $E$ is open
4. $E\cap A_1 \cap A_2$ is dense in $E$ if $E, A_1, A_2$ are open

I know that a set $A$ is dense in $X$ if $\overline{A}=X$. Also I know that $$\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}.$$ But I am not getting how to apply these statements to show that 2 and 4 are correct.

Comment: There are other characterizations of density in a topological space that may be more helpful here. What other definitions of density do you know? 

I personally would approach this problem by thinking in terms of bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is not true. Let $E:=X\setminus A_1$.

(2) is true, as density is a local property. Just think about it, there must be an element of $A_1$ in any neighborhood of $x \in E_1$ and you know it for $x \in X$. I think this hint is big enough.

(3) What could happen to $A_1 \cap A_2$? Look at concrete example with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ for example.

(4) This might be a little trickier. But again use the idea from (2).

Answer (score 1):

For (4): Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be dense open subsets of $X.$ Let $A_3=A_2\cap A_2.$ Then $A_3$ is a dense open subset of $X.$

Proof: Obviously $A_3$ is open. Let $F$ be any non-empty open subset of $X.$ Let $F'=F\cap A_1.$ Then $F'$ is open, and $F'\ne \emptyset$  (because $A_1$ is dense and $F$ is open-and-not-empty) so the dense subset $A_2$ has non-empty intersection with $F'.$ Therefore, for any non-empty open $F$ we have $$F\cap A_3=F\cap A_1\cap A_2=F'\cap A_2\ne \emptyset.$$ So $A_3$ is dense.

Now apply (2) with $A_1$ replaced by $A_3.$

Comment: Another useful little property is that if $A$ is dense and $E$ is open then $\overline E= \overline {E\cap A}.$